# Possibly an error on my credit report, what can I do?

Tags: credit-score, credit-report, dispute

I recently obtained a copy of my credit report. There's one collectable item from Comcast Cable back in 2011 worth $93 that I was supposed to owe (which I don't recall). I dialed Credit Protection Assoc number accompanied by the report to try to pay it off. The account man on the line tells me that apparently Comcast has recalled the debt, and gave me its number.

I followed Comcast's number to talk to a billing representative. She says my account has no balance.

Given the above, is there anything I can do to clear this up and improve my score?

Could this have possibly been a mistake on the report, or is it too late to pay the debt off (so both agencies simply deflect it?)

Comment: Did you continue to have an account with the cable company beyond the time that you owed them money, or could this be a charge for failure to return equipment?

Comment: Good question. I looked at my records and i have switch to verizon fios around that time. I also remember I returned the router on a Sunday when the office was close, and I left it at the door way. It must have never registered.

Answer (score 4):

There are two directions you can go:

(a) ask Comcast to send you a note verifying the account has no balance. They should have no issue doing this.

(b) use the dispute process with the reporting agency. They have 90 days for Comcast to tell them the debt is real or they must remove it.

Note - you should pull the reports from the other two major agencies. This mistake might appear there as well.

Comment: I thought requesting my credit report too frequently can lower my score? Is my scenario an exception?

Comment: You can, and should, pull your report once a year, from all three agencies. The report request is a 'soft' pull and doesn't count against your score. Nor do the "preapproved" offers you get. The real pulls are when you apply for credit.